# Prove the sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis

How can I prove the sequence of functions $x(1-x), x^2(1-x), ...$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$?

I know it converges to $0$ and I know if I differentiate it attains a maximum at $x =\frac{n}{1+n}$ but I can't use that because I need to prove this by definition.

Comment: What do you mea "prove by definition". You want to show $\|f_n\|_{\infty} \to 0$, so is quite reasonable to first find out where $f_n$ attains its maximum. In fact, that gives a rather clean proof!

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan So its okay if I take the derivative here? Because in my book it doesn't show examples of taking derivatives so I was hesitant to use it here. It shows it in the next chapter but not in this one. Is there another way of finding the maximum without using calculus techniques like differentiability ?

Comment: I think that is a very good approach, personally. Once you complete the proof, I recommend that you drop it in as an answer so that others can give you some reputation :)

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan haha its my third post someone downvoted, idk why though. But I will do as you say. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan Is the answer I given correct?

Answer (score 1):

What we need to prove is that, given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $N$ such that for every $n > N$ and for every $x \in[0, 1]$, we have $|x^n(1 - x)-0| < \epsilon.$

$x^n$ and $(1-x)$ are both continuous functions and $x^n(1 - x)$ has a maximum on $[0, 1]$ at $x=\frac{n}{1+n}$ since $\frac{d}{dx}[x^n(1-x)] = -x^n +nx^{n-1}-nx^n = -x-nx+n$ thus $x=\frac{n}{1+n}$.

Then $|x^n(1-x)|<(\frac{n}{n+1})^n(\frac{1}{n+1})<\frac{1}{n+1}<\epsilon.$ Choose $N = \frac{1-\epsilon}{\epsilon}$ therefore for $n>N$ we have $|x^n(1-x)|<\epsilon.$

Comment: Yes, but you need to explain why $$\left ( \frac{n}{n+1}\right )^n < 1$$

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan Is this correct? since $x\in [0,1]$ we have either $x^n$ and $(1-x)$ is less than $1$ or at most $1$ and since the maximum is attained at $x = \frac{n}{n+1}$ we have $(\frac{n}{n+1})^n<1$?

Comment: No No. The variable $x$ has nothing to do with this. You need to know something about $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left( \frac{n}{n+1} \right)^n$$

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan Ohh. We have $\lim_{n\to \infty} \left( \frac{n}{n+1} \right)^n = \lim (1+1/n)^n$ as $n\to \infty$ thus $<1$. Is that correct?

Comment: Well, You need that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = e > 1$$