# Uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis

How can I prove the sequence of functions $x(1-x), x^2(1-x), ...$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$?

I know from my earlier question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549842/prove-the-sequence-of-functions/549863#549863) that I can prove it by taking the derivative. But how can I prove it without taking the derivative since we still haven't defined "derivative" yet in my class? I know I can divide the regions into two pieces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f_n(x) = x^n(1-x)$.

Note that $f_n(0) = f_n(1) = 0$ and $f_n (x) \ge 0$ for $x \in [0,1]$. Hence $f$ has a maximum in $(0,1)$.
Setting $f_n'(x) = 0 $ gives $x = \frac{n}{n+1} $, hence we have $f_n(x) \le \frac{\left( \frac{n}{n+1} \right)^n}{n+1} \le \frac{1}{1+n}$.

Hence $f_n \to 0$ uniformly on $[0,1]$.

**Alternatively**: Let $\epsilon>0$ and choose $\theta \in (0,1)$ such that $1-\theta < \epsilon$. Now choose $N$ such that $\theta^N < \epsilon$. Then for all $n \ge N$, we have $|f_n(x)| < \epsilon.$

To see this, if $x \in [0,\theta]$, we have $|f_n(x)| \le x^n \le \theta^n \le \theta^N < \epsilon$. If $x \in (\theta,1]$, $|f_n(x)| \le 1-x < 1 - \theta < \epsilon$.

Comment: Copper.hat, I already have a solution similar to this but I cant use it since we haven't defined what a derivative is. What I need to do is divide the regions.

Comment: You can still use this solution, it's just a magic number appears. Let me add to the question.

Comment: I updated the answer to avoid the dreaded derivative.

Answer (score 3):

observe that the $x^n$ parts are always smaller or equal to $1$. Now take any $\epsilon > 0$, and consider the regions $[0, 1-\epsilon]$, $[1-\epsilon, 1]$. On the second one all your functions are smaller than $\epsilon$ thanks to the $1-x$ factor. to take care of the first one just take $n$ large enough such that $(1-\epsilon)^n < \epsilon$ and since $1-\epsilon$ is also smaller than $1$ you're done

Comment: Thank you! How were you able to get $[0, 1-\epsilon]$ and $[1-\epsilon,1]$ from?

Comment: well the intuition is that you want to divide your region into two parts, to make your functions small in the region near $1$ you want to use the $(1-x)$ part, then the appropriate choice just pops up